# Creating a button that adds a value to a cell if pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a button, then assigned a macro to it which is in module1. when I select a cell within a range, then press the button, I want that cell to be given a value. if a cell within the range is not selected then pressing the button should pop up with a message box. I am just starting to write the code and already getting an issue.

```
   If Intersect(Target, Range("D12:AS23")) Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Please select a date.", , "Error"
      Exit Sub
   Else
```

Edit: I've got past this issue now using active cell instead of the target. but now I'm struggling again at the next bit. its saying application/object-defined error and highlighting this line. full code below

```
Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Application.SumIf(Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeNames"), Cells(3, 2).Value, Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeID"))
```

```
Sub AddNote()

    Dim SelectedDate As Date
    SelectedDate = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) - 1 + ActiveCell.Value

    If intersect(ActiveCell, range("D12:AS23")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a date.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With Sheets("Notes")
            xtt = Application.InputBox("Insert your Comment here", "Comment")
            If xtt = vbNullString Or xtt = False Then
            End If

            Dim LastRow As Integer
            LastRow = 2 + .listobjects("TblNotes").range.rows.Count
            Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Application.SumIf(Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeNames"), Cells(3, 2).Value, Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeID"))
            Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = SelectedDate
            Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = xht
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue? And in what event handler are you using this code?

Comment: Target? In module1?

Comment: i get an error object required

Comment: If it's in a module, then you would have to include arguments that qualify the `Range` object and `Target`, or the function will have no idea what those things are referring to.

Comment: Should be no problem with your code. Just your code need to create at the worksheet's SelectionChange Event not in a Module.

Comment: If Intersect(Selection, Range("D12:AS23")) Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Please select a date.", , "Error"
      Exit Sub
   Else

Comment: i cant do that because how else can i add that as a macro to my button

Comment: Yes can. Modify your code to this: Intersect(Selection, Range("D12:AS23")). Change Target to Selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working 90% on my own, thanks to @LeeLiFong for tipping me off about "target" being an issue and also @BraX for point int he right direction about including arguements to qualify things. I cant accept my answer for another 48 hours.

```
Dim SelectedDate As Date
SelectedDate = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) - 1 + ActiveCell.Value

If intersect(ActiveCell, range("D12:AS23")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please select a date.", , "Error"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Call SmoothCodeStart
    With Sheets("Notes")
        xt4 = Application.InputBox("Insert your Comment here", "Comment")
        If xt4 = vbNullString Or xt4 = False Then
        End If

        Dim LastRow As Integer
        LastRow = 2 + .listobjects("TblNotes").range.rows.Count
        .Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Application.SumIf(Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeNames"), Cells(3, 2).Value, Sheets("Settings").range("ListEmployeeID"))
        .Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = SelectedDate
        .Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = xt4
    End With
    Call SmoothCodeEnd
End If
```